# Switch between JSF pages with AJAX

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm interested how can I switch between JSF pages using AJAX? In my case, I have ~10 JSF pages which I browse like normal html pages. I would like to fully implement AJAX. Is there any possible solution?

Answer (score 2):

Add "?faces-redirect=true" to the return value of your action method.

For example:

```
    String aListener(){


      return "home.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```